# How to search for a string withing a column of text?

Tags: excel, string-matching

In excel is there a way to search for a string in a column of text. Vlookup function wouldn't work in this case because i am not searching for the exact string but rather want to see if there is even a partial match.

For example i want to search the string "Apple" and Column B has 10 rows of text. I want find if the string "Apple" is present in any of the text in one of those 10 rows in column B.

Comment: `=VLOOKUP("*" & "Apple" & "*", B1:C10,2,FALSE)`

Comment: Thanks a lot, i didn't know vlookup can be used in this fashion. Appreciate the very quick response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(from comments)*

VLOOKUP can use "*" as a wildcard character:

```
=VLOOKUP("*" & "Apple" & "*", B1:C10,2,FALSE)
```